# Not reaching web service on live server but i reach it on local machine in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

am trying to consume a web service in laravel 4.2 but works on local machine but does to work on live server
my controller

```
 ini_set('max_execution_time',10);
            $headers = array(
                "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                "Accept: text/xml",
                "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                "Pragma: no-cache",
                "trace"      => 1,      // enable trace to view what is happening
                "exceptions" => 0,        // disable exceptions
                "cache_wsdl" => 0
            ); //SOAPAction: your op URL

            $vendorCode = Input::get('name');
            $password  =  Input::get('password');

            $client = new SoapClient('https://xxxxxxxxx.asmx?WSDL', $headers);
            $params = array(
                'vendorcode'=> $vendorCode,
                'password'=> $password,
            );

            $results = $client->GetAccountBalance($params);

            $response = $results->GetAccountBalanceResult;
```

the error it brings looks like this

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://XXXXXXXXX.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "https://XXXXXXXXX.asmx?WSDL"

thanks in advance

Comment: Is the WSDL external to your local machine also?

Comment: yes its external